# ¿Como guardar N cantidad de productos en una tabla con Laravel?

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, laravel

Estoy trabajando en un sistema de requisiciones y cuando genero una requisición debería poder guardar N cantidad de productos, tengo el código para añadir mas input y poder ir agregando en una tabla pero no comprendo como podría guardarlos en la base de datos o en alguna parte para poder consultarlos después de guardarlos y poder editarlos

Este es el código de mi formulario para enviar los datos

```
<form method="POST" action="{{ route('requisiciones.store') }}"  role="form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                        @csrf
                        <div class="container-fluid">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-3 ms-auto">
                                    {{ Form::label('Producto') }}
                                    {{ Form::select('partidas_id', $producto, $requi->partidas_id, ['class' => 'form-control' . ($errors->has('partidas_id') ? ' is-invalid' : ''), 'placeholder' => 'Partidas Id']) }}
                                    {!! $errors->first('partidas_id', '<div class="invalid-feedback">:message</div>') !!}
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-3 ms-auto">
                                    {{ Form::label('users_id') }}
                                    {{ Form::select('users_id', $usuario, $requi->users_id, ['class' => 'form-control' . ($errors->has('users_id') ? ' is-invalid' : ''), 'placeholder' => 'Users']) }}
                                    {!! $errors->first('users_id', '<div class="invalid-feedback">:message</div>') !!}
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-3 ms-auto">
                                    {{ Form::label('concepto') }}
                                    {{ Form::text('concepto', $requi->concepto, ['class' => 'form-control' . ($errors->has('concepto') ? ' is-invalid' : ''), 'placeholder' => 'Concepto']) }}
                                    {!! $errors->first('concepto', '<div class="invalid-feedback">:message</div>') !!}
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-3 ms-auto">
                                    {{ Form::label('urgencia') }}
                                    {{ Form::select('urgencia',array('Urgente' => array('Urgente' => 'Urgente'),'No Urgente' => array('No urgente' => 'No urgente'),),
                                    $requi->urgencia, ['class' => 'form-control' . ($errors->has('urgencia') ? ' is-invalid' : ''), 'placeholder' => 'Urgencia']) }}
                                    {!! $errors->first('urgencia', '<div class="invalid-feedback">:message</div>') !!}
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row">
                            @can('aprobador')
                                <div class="col-md-3 ms-auto">
                                    {{ Form::label('status') }}
                                    {{ Form::select('status',array('Aprobada' => array('Aprobada' => 'Aprobada'),'Rechazada' => array('Rechazada' => 'Rechazada'),),
                                    $requi->status, ['class' => 'form-control' . ($errors->has('status') ? ' is-invalid' : ''), 'placeholder' => 'Status']) }}
                                    {!! $errors->first('status', '<div class="invalid-feedback">:message</div>') !!}
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-3 ms-auto">
                                    {{ Form::label('Motivo Rechazo') }}
                                    {{ Form::text('motivoRechazo', $requi->motivoRechazo, ['class' => 'form-control' . ($errors->has('motivoRechazo') ? ' is-invalid' : ''), 'placeholder' => 'Motivo del rechazo']) }}
                                    {!! $errors->first('motivoRechazo', '<div class="invalid-feedback">:message</div>') !!}
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-3 ms-auto">
                                    {{ Form::label('fechaRechazo') }}
                                    {{ Form::date('fechaRechazo', $requi->fechaRechazo, ['class' => 'form-control' . ($errors->has('fechaRechazo') ? ' is-invalid' : ''), 'placeholder' => 'Fecharechazo']) }}
                                    {!! $errors->first('fechaRechazo', '<div class="invalid-feedback">:message</div>') !!}
                                </div>
                                @endcan
                                <div class="col-md-3 ms-auto">
                                    {{ Form::label('comentarios') }}
                                    {{ Form::text('comentarios', $requi->comentarios, ['class' => 'form-control' . ($errors->has('comentarios') ? ' is-invalid' : ''), 'placeholder' => 'Comentarios']) }}
                                    {!! $errors->first('comentarios', '<div class="invalid-feedback">:message</div>') !!}
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-3 ms-auto">
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-3 ms-auto">
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-3 ms-auto">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <br>
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-4 ms-auto">
                                    <label for="descripcion" >Descripción</label>
                                    <br>
                                    <input type="text" name="descripcion" placeholder="Descripción..."  id="descripcion" required>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-4 ms-auto">
                                    <label for="tipo">Tipo</label>
                                    <br>
                                    <select name="Tipo" id="tipo" required>
                                        <option value="Pza">Pza</option>
                                        <option value="Caja">Caja</option>
                                        <option value="Paq">Paq</option>
                                        <option value="Kg">Kg</option>
                                        <option value="M">M</option>
                                        <option value="Litros">Litros</option>
                                        <option value="Ton">Ton</option>
                                    </select> 
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-4 ms-auto">
                                    <label for="cantidad">Cantidad</label>
                                    <br>
                                    <input type="text" name="cantidad" placeholder="Cantidad..."  id="cantidad" required>
                                </div>
                                    <br>
                            </div>
                                    <br>
                            <button id="adicionar" class="btn btn-success" type="button">Adicionar a la tabla</button>
                                    <br>
                            <p>Elementos en la Tabla:
                            <div id="adicionados"></div>
                            </p>
                                <table  id="mytable" class="table table-bordered table-hover ">
                                    <tr>
                                        <th>Descripción</th>
                                        <th>Tipo</th>
                                        <th>Cantidad</th>
                                        <th>Eliminar</th>
                                    </tr>
                                </table>        
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-danger" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                        <button type="input" class="btn btn-outline-success">Save changes</button>
                        </form>
```

Este formulario va dentro de un modal y lo que quiero es que todas las filas de la tabla que fui agregando se guarden pero en la base de datos solo se podria guardar una fila, quisiera que en alguna parte agregara todas las filas para consultar la requisicion y poder exportarla a PDF, en la imagen se muestra algunos productos que fui agregando
[image: Modal de añadir requisicion]

Y este es mi script para que se vayan añadiendo los datos en una tabla

```
<script>
          $(document).ready(function() {
//obtenemos el valor de los input

$('#adicionar').click(function() {
  var descripcion = document.getElementById("descripcion").value;
  var tipo = document.getElementById("tipo").value;
  var cantidad = document.getElementById("cantidad").value;
  var i = 1; //contador para asignar id al boton que borrara la fila
  var fila = '<tr id="row' + i + '"><td>' + descripcion + '</td><td>' + tipo + '</td><td>' + cantidad + '</td><td><button type="button" name="remove" id="' + i + '" class="btn btn-danger btn_remove">Quitar</button></td></tr>'; //esto seria lo que contendria la fila

  i++;

  $('#mytable tr:first').after(fila);
    $("#adicionados").text(""); //esta instruccion limpia el div adicioandos para que no se vayan acumulando
    var nFilas = $("#mytable tr").length;
    $("#adicionados").append(nFilas - 1);
    //le resto 1 para no contar la fila del header
    document.getElementById("tipo").value ="";
    document.getElementById("cantidad").value = "";
    document.getElementById("descripcion").value = "";
  });
$(document).on('click', '.btn_remove', function() {
  var button_id = $(this).attr("id");
    //cuando da click obtenemos el id del boton
    $('#row' + button_id + '').remove(); //borra la fila
    //limpia el para que vuelva a contar las filas de la tabla
    $("#adicionados").text("");
    var nFilas = $("#mytable tr").length;
    $("#adicionados").append(nFilas - 1);
  });
});
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Facil, te recomiendo guardar estos datos como en un JSON que es un string con una estructura. con la funcion json_encode conviertes un array en string, lo que haria en tu caso es juntar todos los registros que se haga en la requisicion en un array de alli lo pasas a json y lo guardas en una BD, por cierto te recomiendo que el campo donde guardes esta informacion no pongas VARCHAR debido a que esta limitado a 255 caracteres, cambias mejor a TEXT, ese no tiene limite creo xD.
Para volver a consultar obvio te traera un JSON solo esas la funcion json_decode para convertirlo en array y ya poder mostrarlo. Si te preguntas que es un JSON bro no te la compliques es un string con un formato diferente y ya xD.

codigo resultado cuando lo conviertes de array a json:

```
[{"descripión":"Tv","tipo":"Pza","Cantidad":"4"},{"descripión":"lavadora","tipo":"Pza","Cantidad":"3"},{"descripión":"nose we","tipo":"Pza","Cantidad":"4"},{"descripión":"perrros","tipo":"Pza","Cantidad":"5"},{"descripión":"gatos","tipo":"Pza","Cantidad":"74"},{"descripión":"luces","tipo":"Pza","Cantidad":"64"}]
```

Codigo resultado cuando lo conviertes de json a array :

```
Array(
[0] => stdClass Object
    (
        [descripión] => Tv
        [tipo] => Pza
        [Cantidad] => 4
    )

[1] => stdClass Object
    (
        [descripión] => lavadora
        [tipo] => Pza
        [Cantidad] => 3
    )

[2] => stdClass Object
    (
        [descripión] => nose we
        [tipo] => Pza
        [Cantidad] => 4
    )

[3] => stdClass Object
    (
        [descripión] => perrros
        [tipo] => Pza
        [Cantidad] => 5
    )

[4] => stdClass Object
    (
        [descripión] => gatos
        [tipo] => Pza
        [Cantidad] => 74
    )

[5] => stdClass Object
    (
        [descripión] => luces
        [tipo] => Pza
        [Cantidad] => 64
    )
```

)

Codigo de prueba:

```
// Registro de prueba
    $registro = array(
        0=>array('descripión' => 'Tv', 'tipo' => 'Pza', 'Cantidad' => '4'),
        1=>array('descripión' => 'lavadora', 'tipo' => 'Pza', 'Cantidad' => '3'),
        2=>array('descripión' => 'nose we', 'tipo' => 'Pza', 'Cantidad' => '4'),
        3=>array('descripión' => 'perrros', 'tipo' => 'Pza', 'Cantidad' => '5'),
        4=>array('descripión' => 'gatos', 'tipo' => 'Pza', 'Cantidad' => '74'),
        5=>array('descripión' => 'luces', 'tipo' => 'Pza', 'Cantidad' => '64'),
    );

    // Pasamos el registro a string json para guardar en la base de datos, el json_jnescaped sirve para mostrar los acentos correctamente óáúí. si quieres los puedes quitar
    $registro_string = json_encode($registro, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);

    // Mostramos el registro en string
    var_dump($registro_string);

    // Pasamos el registro a array para poder manipularlo
    $registro_array = json_decode($registro_string);

    // Mostramos el registro en array
    var_dump($registro_array);
```